# How to define a shape in Dart (Flutter) with multiple x y values and determine if point is inside shape

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, coordinates, area

I want to define a two-dimensional shape in Dart by providing a list of x and y values and then check if a point (that also has an x and a y value) is inside the shape or not.

Preferably without any external packages.

A is outside the shape, B is inside in my example.

This question would help me and @override

[image: Example image]

Comment: check `Path` class